# Application Name And Application Icon from Application Package Name In Android

Tags: android, package

I have stored package name of an application by the following code .

```
 mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

       for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages)
       {
            String pck = packageInfo.packageName;
            if(pck.startsWith("com.google") )
            {
                 app = new APP(R.drawable.ic_launcher,packageInfo.packageName);
                 application_package.add(app);
                 continue;
            }
            if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
            if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("com.walton.taskkiller")) continue;
            app = new APP(R.drawable.ic_launcher,packageInfo.packageName);
            application_package.add(app);
               }
```

Now I want to know Application name and application icon . How can I get application name and application icon from application package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the instance of package manager:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
```

Now for getting App name and App icon via ApplicationInfo instance:

```
String appName = applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)

Drawable appIcon = applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
```

Comment: How to set this drawable icon to an imageview ?

Comment: Like this: `imageview.setImageDrawable(applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));`

Comment: how to set it into Universal Image Loader I stuck any possibility pls @TheLittleNaruto